# How to display spin.js before executing some function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, web-worker, spin.js

I want to display a spinner before some complicated function, i.e. dummyCounter(). The code looks like:

```
function add1() {
  msg.html('start counting~<br \>');
  document.body.appendChild(div);  
  spinner.spin(div);  
  // display spinner before doing stuff

  dummyCounter();  
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eGB5t/

However the spinner shows after the dummyCounter() function is finished.

I try to use callback to force spinner display earlier but still no good. Can anybody help? Thanks.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eGB5t/2/

Comment: use settimeOut function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a thinking failure. Spinners are usually used for asynchronous tasks, so you can see that there is something in progress. A callback is then used to remove the spin when the async action has finished, since you cannot tell before it starts when it will finish.

I made up a quick example to show you, how such an async function would work in this case, and you can clearly see how the spinner appears slightly before "google finished" appears.
http://jsfiddle.net/eGB5t/4/

I added the following instead of your counting method:

```
$.ajax("http://google.de").always(function() {
    msg.append("google finished");
});
```

You add the spin before you count, then it counts, then you could remove the spinner. This is perfecty fine. Thing is, if you would count to let's say 9999999999999 (so it would take some seconds), a normal for loop like you're doing is completely blocking the browser, so you won't have any repaints (and therefore no spinner) at all, while the loop is running.

What you would have to do (in this case) is to introduce a worker to have [multithreading functionality in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30197/3269863).

Answer (score 0):

```
var x;
function add1() {
  msg.html('start counting~<br \>');

spinner.spin(div);
x= setTimeout(document.body.appendChild(div),500);
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this [thread][1]. The spinner shows, but it doesn't spin. [jsfiddle][2]
[1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227611/jquery-force-display-of-modified-dom
[2]:http://jsfiddle.net/eGB5t/3/

Comment: because you put the setTimeout delay to 0 and by doing this you are not using the advantages of this function you should put some time like i did in my answer `500` and it will spin