# Showing "waiting" modal _before_ my lengthy table sort starts (and disappear afterwards)

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I just want to do three things in order.

My table has thousands of rows and takes a while to sort. I would like my "waiting" modal to display during the sort, but the page waits for the sorting to complete before attempting to display the modal.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxworys0/14/). (You can increase or decrease `bignumber` to get a sorting delay you can see but isn't annoying.)

I first tried:

```
//CSS:   body.loading .waitingModal {display: block;}

$('body').toggleClass("loading");         // happens second!
sortTable(currentdirection,columnno);     // takes ages and happens first
$('body').toggleClass("loading");         // happens third
```

If I comment out the last line or cause an error before it, the table sorts, **then** the modal appears.

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227611/jquery-force-display-of-modified-dom?rq=1), my next attempt worked once but then the loading modal never came again:

```
$('body').toggleClass("loading");   
setTimeout(function() {           //loading works but not if you click again
    sortTable(order,1);
    $('body').toggleClass("loading");
}
```

Web pages advising people suggest I should use `jQuery.Deferred` rather than entangle myself in callback hell, and since I couldn't see where to put a callback and callback hell doesn't sound fun I went along with it.

I read questions on [How to use jQuery deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used) and [then vs done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done) and most promisingly, [this answer's Example 1 of chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601230), but everyone seems to assume I have a deferred/promise already turning up from some ajax call or something.

My first attempt to chain some `.then(...)` calls didn't work, because literally nothing happened:

```
$.Deferred().then(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass("loading");    //doesn't happen
}).then(function(){
    sortTable(order,1);                  //doesn't happen
}).then(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass("loading");    //doesn't happen
});
```

Using the `beforeStart` parameter got my modal displayed, but nothing else:

```
$.Deferred(function(it){
    $('body').toggleClass("loading");    //happens first, hooray!
}).then(function(){
    sortTable(order,1);                  //doesn't happen
}).then(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass("loading");    //doesn't happen
});
```

I then tried to chain some deferred `then`s, resolving and passing the deferred explicitly, but I clearly don't understand how this works:

```
$.Deferred().then(function(it){
    $('body').toggleClass("loading");    //still happens second
    it.resolve();
    return it.promise();
}).then(function(){
    sortTable(order,1);                  //happens first
}).then(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass("loading");    //happens third
});
```

Lastly, I've tried resolving a `deffered` on the change event on the body

```
function loadingNow(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $('body').toggleClass("loading")     // happens
      .change(function(){
        deferred.resolve()
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}            
loadingNow().then(function(){
    sortTable(order,1);                  //doesn't happen
}).then(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass("loading");    //doesn't happen
});
```

Doesn't matter if I toggle the class after adding the change event handler:

```
function loadingNow(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $('body').change(function(){
        deferred.resolve()
    }).toggleClass("loading");    // happens
    return deferred.promise();
}            
loadingNow().then(function(){
    sortTable(order,1);                  //doesn't happen
}).then(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass("loading");    //doesn't happen
});
```

Honestly, I didn't expect it to be this difficult to persuade jQuery to do three things in order. Perhaps there's a much simpler thing I haven't thought of. I don't mind if it's callbacks or `Deferred` done right, but if it's brief and relatively clear that would be a huge bonus.

Answer (score 1):

**You almost had it**. The big issue is that listening for the `change` event on `<body>` does not trigger when a class changes. That event is for form elements like text inputs.

Your logic will work with a listener that triggers on class changes, like `DOMSubtreeModified`, like so:

```
function loadingNow(){
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   $('body').one('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
       deferred.resolve()
   }).toggleClass("loading");
   return deferred.promise();
}           

$("#sortButNoLoading").click(function(){
   order *= -1;
   loadingNow().then(function() {
      sortTable(order,1);   
      $('body').toggleClass("loading"); //happens third
   })
})
```

### Notes for proper implementation:

1. The `DOMSubtreeModified` will fire any time anything changes anywhere on `<body>` or below, so make sure you stop listening for that once you fired the function in response to that. You can use `$().one()` instead of `$().on()` to automatically destroy the listener after it's fired once.
2. As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731807/listen-for-change-of-class-in-jquery#comment87092348_17881562), `DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated and you should migrate to something else.
3. [See the "working" fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lstuz4en/).

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Unfortunately, like my setTimeout version in [an updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxworys0/14/), this works once, but on subsequent sorts the loading doesn't show again. I tried changing `one` to `on`, in your jsfiddle but that didn't help.

Comment: [This version of your fiddle seems to work every time](http://jsfiddle.net/hsdq1tb3/)

Comment: Ah drat. That does indeed work in Chrome but fails subsequent times in Firefox which is my main browser. Here's me thinking that libraries like jQuery eliminated cross-browser incompatabilities.